# Paint columns of multirows latex

Tags: tables, multirow, colortbl, rowcolor, cellcolor

I'm trying to coloring a table with multirows. I want to "Formação Candeias" cell to be gray, "Rifte" cell to be pink and "Pré-rifte" cell to be blue.

[image]

Below I'll show my code. I've tried a lot of ways, but nothing worked.

```
\begin{table}[!h]\large
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
     \rowcolor{yellow}  \textbf{Rochas geradoras}   & \textbf{Rochas reservatório} & \textbf{Sequências}  \\ \hline
     \multirow{8}{*}{Formação Candeias}
    & Formação Taquipe \cellcolor{pink} & \multirow{5}{*}{\shortstack{Rifte}} \\ \cline{2-2}
     & Formação Pojuca \cellcolor{pink} &\\ \cline{2-2} 
     & Formação Marfim \cellcolor{pink} & \\ \cline{2-2} 
      & Formação Maracangalha \cellcolor{pink} &\\ \cline{2-2}
     & Formação Candeias \cellcolor{pink} & \\ \cline{2-3}
     & Formação Água Grande \cellcolor{cyan}& \multirow{3}{*}{\shortstack{Pré-rifte}}\\\cline{2-2}
     & Formação Sergi \cellcolor{cyan} &\\ \cline{2-2} 
     & Formação Aliança \cellcolor{cyan} & \\ \cline{2-2} 
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Resumo das principais rochas geradoras e rochas reservatório da Bacia do Recôncavo.}
    \label{tab:1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Use the `tabularray` package, or see the `multirow` documentation, page 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern packages are available to make tabular layout easier by splitting design from content.

The font, color, alignment, etc. of the cell, or a row or other set of cells are specified from  "outside" of the data.

Therefore, these elements can be easily changed during the design phase without altering the raw content of the table. At the same time the raw  content can be updated without altering the design.

This example is based on `nicematrix`.

The command `\RowStyle` gives the formatting instructions that will be applied to
each cell of the current row (the first in the example).

`\Block{<nrows>-<ncolumns>}{<cell content>}`  places an
element in the center of a rectangle of merged cells of nrows x ncolumns.

Between `\CodeBefore` and `\Body` are the instructions for coloring cells or sets of cells :
for example `\rectanglecolor{cyan}{7-2}{9-2}` will put the color cyan in the cells of column 2 from row 7 to row 9.

`hvlines` draws all lines (or `vlines`: only vertical lines, or `hlines`: only horizontal lines)

`cell-space-limits` expand cells vertically for easier reading. In this example, the header was expanded a bit more.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]\large
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ c c c}[hvlines, cell-space-limits=4pt]
        \CodeBefore
        \rectanglecolor{pink}{2-2}{6-2}
        \rectanglecolor{cyan}{7-2}{9-2}
        \rectanglecolor{gray!20}{2-1}{9-1}
        \rectanglecolor{red!30}{2-3}{6-3}
        \rectanglecolor{blue!40}{7-3}{9-3}
        \Body           
        \RowStyle[rowcolor=yellow, cell-space-limits=8pt]{\bfseries}
        Rochas geradoras                & Rochas reservatório   & Sequências  \\ 
        \Block{8-1}{Formação Candeias}  & Formação Taquipe      & \Block{5-1}{Rifte} \\ 
                                        & Formação Pojuca       & \\
                                        & Formação Marfim       & \\
                                        & Formação Maracangalha & \\ 
                                        & Formação Candeias     & \\
                                        & Formação Água Grande  & \Block{3-1}{Pré-rifte}\\
                                        & Formação Sergi        & \\ 
                                        & Formação Aliança      & \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{Resumo das principais rochas geradoras e rochas reservatório da Bacia do Recôncavo.}
    \label{tab:1}
\end{table} 
    
\end{document}
```

The first time it will compile multiple times.

Comment: Thanks! it is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!! If the answer meets your requirement, please accept it by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler with `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]\large\centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        vlines,hlines,colspec={ccc},
        row{1}={yellow, font=\bfseries},
        cell{2}{1}={r=8}{},
        cell{2}{3}={r=5}{},
        cell{7}{3}={r=3}{},
        cell{2-6}{2}={pink},
        cell{7-Z}{2}={cyan},
        }
        Rochas geradoras & Rochas reservatório & Sequências \\ 
        Formação Candeias & Formação Taquipe & Rifte \\ 
        & Formação Pojuca & \\
        & Formação Marfim & \\
        & Formação Maracangalha & \\ 
        & Formação Candeias & \\
        & Formação Água Grande & Pré-rifte\\
        & Formação Sergi & \\ 
        & Formação Aliança & \\
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{Resumo das principais rochas geradoras e rochas reservatório da Bacia do Recôncavo.\label{tab:1}}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]